# PostgreSQL regexp_replace trouble ignoring preceded by

Tags: regex, postgresql

am trying the following regex_replace statement in PostgreSQL (9.2)

```
 # SELECT regexp_replace('_this._is_a_long_entry._of.nonsense_text', '\._|^_', '$','g');
```

#### Objective:

is to replace all underscore characters *preceded by a period* with '$'. Am also replacing the underscore anchored at position 1; this is working. I'd like to cram both matches into the one statement. All of this is to develop a mechanism for pushing some weird text we have into a PostreSQL ltree structure.

#### Issue:

How to make the first replacement above work, without molesting the period character?

I'd like to see the result look like this:

`$this.$is_a_long_entry.$of.nonsense_text`

Note: Have also tried explicit capture of the underscore, but the PG implementation seems to ignore this:

```
# SELECT regexp_replace('_this.is_long_entry._of.nonsense_text', '\.(_)|^_', '$','g');
```

Comment: @m.buettner: I have tried that, yes - though I think the **or** syntax must compare _full_ expressions; I don't know that regex can swap like that.
In any case, PostgreSQL hiccups with: ERROR:  invalid regular expression: quantifier operand invalid.
Thanks for the swing, though.

Comment: the problem might be the `?` then but alternation (`|`) does generally work in subpatterns in regex. how about `\.(_)|^(_)`?

Comment: @m.buettner: (Your logic is subtly different there, though - in that the match object doesn't span the alternation - In any case, yes; I've tried this variant, too. This works... partly)
It substitutes, but doesn't leave the period char in place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT regexp_replace('_this._is_a_long_entry._of.nonsense_text'
                     ,'(\.|^)_' -- capture the preceding char (none at start)
                     , '\1$'    -- use the captured char
                     ,'g');     -- globally
```

This is assuming [`standard_conforming_strings = ON`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-compatible.html#GUC-STANDARD-CONFORMING-STRINGS).

Comment: Erwin! Great! That worked! 
I had tried a variant of PostgreSQL's \1 referencing earlier - clearly got it wrong. Many thanks for the answer. That alternation _within_ the subpattern is a new one for me; tks to @m.buettner and you for that.
(standard_conforming_strings = ON by default in 9.2, I believe)

Comment: @DrLou: Cool. :) You're right about `standard_conforming_strings`. It's on by default since 9.1. But it's just a default ...